# python groupby using comparator function/lambda instead of key function

Tags: python

I have a list of ints

```
l = [17811, 17831, 17843, 28996, 37606, 44325, 44365, 44387]
```

I want to return groups that are within a certain distance of one another, say 30:

```
[[17811, 17831, 17843], [28996], [37606], [44325], [44365, 44387]]
```

I'd like to have a function which allows me to pass a comparator:

```
magic.groupby(l, lambda(a,b): abs(a-b) < 30)
```

Does such a simple expression exist?

Comment: What if a single number belongs to two groups, ex: [1, 29, 58]?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Should all the members of the group have an abs distance < 30, or should an element be included whenever *some* other member of the group has an abs distance < 30?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a custom class:

```
import itertools
class Val:
   def __init__(self, _v):
     self.v = _v
   def __eq__(self, _obj):
     return abs(self.v - _obj.v) < 30

l = [17811, 17831, 17839, 28996, 37606, 44325, 44365, 44387]
result = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=Val)]
```

Output:

```
[[17811, 17831, 17839], [28996], [37606], [44325], [44365, 44387]]
```

Comment: @kaya3 is correct, a weird equality can lead to weird results: https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/ChillyCulturedNaturaldocs